# Dynamic css based on the nth level

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation tree that continuly build a nested list of categories.

Is there a way to indent the nested category 5px, to the nth level

```
/* the traditional way, but this is fixed to 1 level */
#sidebar ul li ul {
    margin-left:5px;
}
#sidebar ul li ul li ul {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS3 you can use nth-child selector

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```
#sidebar ul li ul:nth-child(1) {
margin-left:5px;
}
```